# Laravel 5.1 Sessions not working

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.1

I have fresh Laravel 5.1 distribution.
The first thing I started from is to extend the `Guard` class in order to implement my own auth driver. I'm really new with Laravel. So, here is what I did so far.

config/auth.php

```
'driver' => 'crm',
```

Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php

```
   public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        Auth::extend(
            'crm',
            function ($app) {
                $model = $app['config']['auth.model'];
                $provider = new EloquentUserProvider($app['hash'], $model);

                return new CrmGuard($provider, $app->make('session.store'));
            }
        );
    }
```

Currently, I already have a user id, stored in session array and I can access it via

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'];
```

But I want to use a Laravel build in session management.
I'm trying to rewrite `user` method of `Guard` class in my `CrmGuard` class and I need to get those values from session, I was trying like so

`$id = $this->session->get('user_id');`

and so

`session('user_id')`

Here is how I'm trying to call the `user` method while testing

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user();
   //return view('welcome');
});
```

But it always return NULL, what I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Is this route covered by the `web` middleware? You can quickly check with `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: It says that I'm using `auth` middleware, what I could do?

Comment: Probably because I added 'middleware' => 'auth' to my route, because I need all routes to be secure, but when I'm adding 'middleware' => 'web' it says that `Class web does not exist`

Comment: It seems that 'middleware' => 'web' is Laravel 5.2 feature, but not 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel's session driver is made a little bit difference that the PHP session so it won't work in this way:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'];
```

It's store in file (server side) by deafualt (you can change this driver) and just expose (to the client side) for a request. Instead of using PHP session, use Laravel's session build-in driver with `\Session::get()` and `Session::put()` that you can read here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Comment: Sorry, if I was not clear enough, but I need to use `php` session mechanism, because `'user_id'` value is provided by another application, not something that I created via Laravel itself

Comment: What means: "because 'user_id' value is provided by another application"? If this comes from another app then you will never get to the right session cookie. It dosn't metter if it's *Laravel* or not.

Comment: well, yeah, it seems wierd enough. I have custom web application, where I added a Laravel project (just placed Laravel directory into the root directory of custom app). That is what I have. And I can access session values provided by custom app by `$_SESSION['user_id'];` in my Laravel project. But anyway, your answer was helpful, now I see that this is the only existing way for me to get those values.